# Memory leak when repeatedly loading large JSON data

Tags: jquery, debugging, memory-leaks, httprequest

This is happening even without processing or storing the returned data.

Here is the context:

The HTML contains

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="formPanel" style="width:100%">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <span style="vertical-align:middle;">
    <span>Date:
        <input id="datePicker" name="DatePicker" maxlength="10" value="20130128"/>
    </span>
        <input id="go-btn" style="width:80px;" type="button" value="Go"/>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

And the JavaScript is

```
$(function(){
    // Extracted the previously anonymous function to reduce memory used to store "compiled code"
    function processData(data) {
        //process data
    }
    // Extracted the previously anonymous function to reduce memory used to store "compiled code"
    function clickHandler() {
        var keys = ['googlechrome','firefox','opera', 'webkit', 'ie']; 
        for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            /* Previously a method call
             */        
            var date = $("#datePicker").val().replace(/-/g, ''),
                // A local URL, That returns a max of 5MB.
                url  = "/get_usage?date="+date;

            url += '&user_agent=' + keys[i];
            url += "&min_count=250";


            $.getJSON(url, processData);
        } 

    }
    $("#go-btn").click(clickHandler);
});
```

On one click the actual size of data received is about 10MB, but when I check the Memory column in Chrome's Task Manager is way above 30MB, & after some time it Garbage collects about 4MB (Don't know if that is unrelated).

I'm suspecting jQuery's getJSON method because on removing it & increasing the array size by ten fold, there wasn't much of a difference in the overall memory.

Comment: Is `processData` empty in your tests as it is above? What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: the memory that is allocated is not necessarily only the memory that is required for your data. other resources, that are required to execute your code, could also be loaded on demand at that time. so to be sure that you really have a leak you should execute your code once, then look at the memory, and then execute the same code another time (or multiple times). another thing to mention is that chrome does keep-alive requests. which stay active until the server disconnects them.

Comment: I see a bug report #6388 that is fixed in jQuery 1.8, but that is for JSONP. If you're on an older version, I would suggest that you try moving up to 1.9 along with the migrate plugin (you'll be able to slowly update any deprecated function usage).

Comment: Thanks @ErikNedwidek I will try upgrading to 1.9. If that does not fix this I'll update the question.

Comment: @t.niese As I had mentioned in the question, on removing the line containing the $.getJSON method, I did not have a leak in memory.
I'm guessing that this is the issue with JSONP calls that Erik has mentioned. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I had mentioned in the question, on removing the line containing the $.getJSON method, I did not have a leak in memory. I'm guessing that this is the issue with JSONP calls that Erik has mentioned. Thanks for the response